# How to remove the border of edittextfield in android

Tags: android, android-layout

How can I remove the border of a Edittext field in android. Actually it looks like this

http://pbrd.co/V34sN7

With this layout code

```
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/login_error"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background_normal"
        android:visibility="invisible" 
        android:textColor="#FF0000"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        />
```

Also the alignment of the text is not on the right side although I defined it.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can customize your `EditText` by using the following xml layout

Save the following code as`yourWishName.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<selector
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

//You can change the color of the edit text here which removes the border line as well
 <item android:state_focused="true" >
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <gradient
            android:startColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:endColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:angle="270" />
        <stroke
            android:width="3dp"
            android:color="#F8B334" />
        <corners
            android:radius="12dp" /> 
    </shape>
</item>  
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <gradient
            android:startColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:endColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:angle="270" />
        <stroke
            android:width="0dp"
            android:color="#000000" />
        <corners
            android:radius="12dp" /> 
    </shape>
</item>
</selector>
```

In EditText call the xml `android:background="@drawable/yourWishName"`

To Align right Use `android:gravity="right"`

Hope this helps

Answer (score 17):

Simply, You can use following in your `xml` file to make `EditText` background clear:

```
android:background="@null"
```

Answer (score 6):

Programmatic method:

```
setBackgroundDrawable(null);
```

Or, since setBackgroundDrawable() is deprectated in API 16:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16)
    setBackground(null);
else
    setBackgroundDrawable(null);
```

Comment: uh... the turns my entire EditText black, i can't see a thing.

Answer (score 3):

You have to create a custom drawable nine patch file which hasn't got a border. [Here you find a tutorial](http://radleymarx.com/blog/simple-guide-to-9-patch/) And the `android:layout_gravity="right"` not means that the text is aligned to the right. It aligns the layout to the right. You have to use `android:gravity="right"`.