# how to remove border of edittext field

Tags: java, android, android-layout, layout, android-edittext

I have created a login layout but in this layout edittext field border is overlap.
I want to remove the `top border` of second edit text field. please guide me.
here is the link 
[screen](http://plus.google.com/photos/115585035204792909450/albums/5599113500585388033/5962172769461530962?banner=pwa&authkey=CP3uq8zM2JH9LA&pid=5962172769461530962&oid=115585035204792909450/)

I want to make layout exactly like this. Here is my `XML code`.

**round_edittext.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />

    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#9999" />

    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="1dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="1dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="1dp"
        android:topRightRadius="1dp" />

</shape>
```

**activity_mail.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/save"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#00000000"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:src="@drawable/no_smslogo_text" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40sp"
        android:layout_marginRight="40sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
        android:background="@drawable/round_edittext"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/mobile_icon"
        android:drawablePadding="5dp"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:hint="Mobile Number"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="8sp"
        android:paddingTop="8sp"
        android:textSize="15dp" >
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40sp"
        android:layout_marginRight="40sp"
        android:background="@drawable/round_edittext"
        android:drawable="@drawable/pin_icon"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/mobile_icon"
        android:drawablePadding="5dp"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:hint="Pin Number"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="8sp"
        android:paddingTop="8sp"
        android:textSize="15dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/signin"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40sp"
        android:layout_marginRight="40sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Sign In"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="15dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: See this answer for the programmatic method: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21822662/534898

Comment: And this for xml way http://stackoverflow.com/a/29249724/4101725

Answer (score 24):

Use it, this is working for me

```
<EditText  
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:hint="@string/hello" 
android:background="#00000000"
/>
```

Comment: You could also use @android:color/white rather than #00000000. I would think that it would be slightly more standard but wouldn't really make any difference otherwise.

Answer (score 4):

you need to use layer list for this

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <!-- Border -->
    <item>
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="#f000"></solid>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <!-- Body -->
    <item android:left="2dip"
          android:bottom="2dp"
          android:right="2dp">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="#ffafafaf"></solid>
        </shape> 
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: it romove the top border of first edittext too. i just want to remove the overlap border.

Comment: First time when the view gets loaded it slietly shows upper border for few seconds..facing this issue

Answer (score 4):

I did it by keeping the background transparent like this:

```
<EditText
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
/>
```

Answer (score 3):

You have two solution for this

1. You can set shape on layout background and put two edit text in the layout.
2. Currently you're using one shape for edit text round. You can use two
   shapes; different ones that have upper border and other have bellow
   border.

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/save"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#00000000"
    android:clickable="false" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/round_edittext"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40sp"
        android:layout_marginRight="40sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
        android:background="#00000000"
        android:drawablePadding="5dp"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:hint="Mobile Number"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="8sp"
        android:paddingTop="8sp"
        android:textSize="15dp" >
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40sp"
        android:layout_marginRight="40sp"
        android:background="#00000000"
        android:drawablePadding="5dp"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:hint="Pin Number"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="8sp"
        android:paddingTop="8sp"
        android:textSize="15dp" />
</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/signin"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="40sp"
    android:layout_marginRight="40sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Sign In"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="15dp" />
```

Answer (score 3):

use two drawables for your edittext.

One with padding top:

round_edittext.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />

<stroke
    android:width="1dp"
    android:color="#9999" />
<!-- add this padding for top -->
<padding android:top="2dp" />
<corners
    android:bottomLeftRadius="1dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="1dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="1dp"
    android:topRightRadius="1dp" />

</shape>
```

and Second without padding:

round_edittext.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />

<stroke
    android:width="1dp"
    android:color="#9999" />

<corners
    android:bottomLeftRadius="1dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="1dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="1dp"
    android:topRightRadius="1dp" />

</shape>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can customise your edit text by using the following xml layout

Save the following code asyourWishName.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<selector
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

//You can change the color of the edit text here which removes the border line as well
 <item android:state_focused="true" >
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <gradient
            android:startColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:endColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:angle="270" />
        <stroke
            android:width="3dp"
            android:color="#F8B334" />
        <corners
            android:radius="12dp" /> 
    </shape>
</item>  
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <gradient
            android:startColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:endColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:angle="270" />
        <stroke
            android:width="0dp"
            android:color="#000000" />
        <corners
            android:radius="12dp" /> 
    </shape>
</item>
</selector>
```

In EditText call the xml android:background="@drawable/yourWishName"

To Align right Use android:gravity="right"

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

use this::

```
              <EditText
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:background="#00000000"
                android:hint="Username"
                />
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to go about this:

One is by adding a custom background to the editText using

```
 android:background="@drawable/customBackground
```

or by setting the background as transparent

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

I would suggest to use the first way if you want to further customize your view background instead of just removing it. Custom shape drawables are easy to create and apply to the view through XML or programatically.